# Search and replace random word

Tags: php, arrays, design-patterns, random

well, first of all let me say, before posting this I've tested many things, many time, but currently, I don't actually know what else to do, because nothing works fine for me.

This is the code I have currently:

```
<?php
// These are the arrays given by the application. All of them has an "%s" within.
// For example...
$arrs = array(
    "this is a %s array" => "converted1 %s text", 
    "value %s test" => "converted2 %s text", 
    "test %s test" => "converted3 %s text"
); 

$text = "This is a random text. Which can contains or not some of the expressions listed above. In this case it contains this: this is a magic array, value hey test, test php test";

// The output should be:
// "This is a random text. Which can contains or not some of the expressions listed above. In this case it contains this: CONVERTED magic TEXT, CONVERTED2 hey TEXT, CONVERTED3 php TEXT"

foreach($arrs as $k => $v){
    // Seriously, I don't know what's next here... also I'm thinking this foreach is not right here.
}

?>
```

The main objective, is to write something random in a textbox input. So I check within the textbox if some of the array keys (`$arrs`) has been filled in. The problem, is that I can not detect it using `strpos`, due %s will be always random, so it's a bit harder to find its position...

Let's say I write "this is a random array" (it is into the array), so if we check its value, we'll see it would be "converted1 RANDOM text".

I've tested for using patterns, also with `explode();`, and `preg_replace_callback`, and nothing works for me. This is really driving me crazy...

Thank you very much guys.

Comment: Regular expressions are the way to go, but you won't be able to use `%s` to match the inner word.  It will be something more like `value (.*?) test` to match any character non-greedily between `value` and `test`.  You could of course limit it to just alphabetic characters, using `value ([a-z]*?) test` etc.

Comment: Hi @JamesThorpe, the problem is that the `value (.*?) test` is completelly dynamic. Would it that solve that problem?

Comment: Don't entirely follow you, but the string used to create a regular expression could be built up dynamically, yes

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression.

```
<?php
$pattern = '~this is a ([^ ]*) array~U';
$replace = 'converted1 $1 text';
$text = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$text);
```

you have assoc array already, you can change keys to be regular expressions and values to replace strings (with escaped group like *$1* above). Also within **foreach()** you can check first:

```
<?php
if (preg_match($k,$text)) {
    // do the replacing here
}
```

**Note:**
I've used **[^ ]*** to match single word. It's not only way, it may not be the best way. You can also use **\w**, but I personally don't like it :)

**Edit:**

Here you go with ready code that works (just tested it on my XAMPP)

```
<?php
$arrs = array(
    "~this is a ([^ ]*) array~U" => "converted1 $1 text", 
    "~value ([^ ]*) test~U" => "converted2 $1 text", 
    "~test ([^ ]*) test~U" => "converted3 $1 text"
); 

$text = "This is a random text. Which can contains or not some of the expressions listed above. In this case it contains this: this is a magic array, value hey test, test php test";

foreach($arrs as $k => $v){
    if (preg_match($k,$text)) {
        $text = preg_replace($k,$v,$text);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: This is giving me this error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Empty regular expression.

Comment: As I said - use it within foreach loop after you change your array to be have regular expressions as keys and replace strings as values.

Comment: Thanks, I've been testing it but I get the following error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: Ok, I see you haven't understand me. Check my answer again, I've posted full working script. (you may want to echo results)

Comment: thank you so much, I see your code works awesome. But there's a bit problem. In this case, the identifier "([^ ]*)" and $1 should be the same. Just like I've posted above with the identifier "%s" (it can be different form that), but must be equal. I've tested by giving $1 to key and value, but doesn't works...

Comment: You misunderstand regular expressions. ([^ ]*) captures any word (to be more exact - any string without space), and $1 takes that captured string and pastes it. Use my code, echo $text before loop and after loop. Test it.

Comment: Yes, I've tested and it works great, but I mean I can not use that, let's say I have this `array("value %s one", "value %s two", "value %s tree")` in this case, all of them should change each other... it doesn't matter if the identifier is %s or any other one. What I mean is that this should allow multiple values...

Comment: Then change your topic question, because you asked for a way to replace some strings while preserving one word within them and you gave us example string. That string doesn't contain any **%s**.

I think you should redesign your question and give real example of code.